# Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed 6

Tags: vba, excel

Okay. Just this last issue I hope. I have my code in another area and was getting some great help. I am assuming he (Ratafia) is very busy and have not heard back today.So I thought I would repost here. I am getting this runtime error on line RwLast = Range("AI" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row It is also not entering data on the next row down when I hit submit. It is replacing the data on line one row which I do not want. Needs to add to each row when a form is filled out and submitted. Any help will be greatly appriciated. The code for the excel sheet is below.

```
           Option Explicit
Dim WrkSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim ssheet As Workbook
Dim cellVal1 As String, cellVal2 As String, cellVal3 As String, cellVal4 As String, cellVal5 As String, cellVal6 As String, cellVal7 As String, cellVal8 As String, cellVal9 As String, cellVal10 As String, cellVal11 As String, cellVal12 As String
Dim cellVal13 As String, cellVal14 As String, cellVal15 As String, cellVal16 As String, cellVal17 As String, cellVal18 As String, cellVal19 As String, cellVal20 As String, cellVal21 As String, cellVal22 As String
Dim cellVal23 As String, cellVal24 As String, cellVal25 As String, cellVal26 As String, cellVal27 As String, cellVal28 As String, cellVal29 As String, cellVal30 As String, cellVal31 As String, cellVal32 As String, cellVal33 As String, cellVal34 As String

Dim shtCmb As String
Dim RwLast As Long

shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value
If shtCmb = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please choose a month.", vbOKOnly
    Me.cmbListItem1.SetFocus
End If

cellVal1 = Me.cmbListItem1.Text
cellVal2 = Me.cmbListItem2.Text
cellVal3 = Me.cmbListItem3.Text
cellVal4 = Me.TextBox31.Text
cellVal5 = Me.TextBox1.Text
cellVal6 = Me.TextBox2.Text
cellVal7 = Me.TextBox3.Text
cellVal8 = Me.TextBox4.Text
cellVal9 = Me.TextBox5.Text
cellVal10 = Me.TextBox6.Text
cellVal11 = Me.TextBox7.Text
cellVal12 = Me.TextBox8.Text
cellVal13 = Me.TextBox9.Text
cellVal14 = Me.TextBox10.Text
cellVal15 = Me.TextBox11.Text
cellVal16 = Me.TextBox12.Text
cellVal17 = Me.TextBox13.Text
cellVal18 = Me.TextBox14.Text
cellVal19 = Me.TextBox15.Text
cellVal20 = Me.TextBox16.Text
cellVal21 = Me.TextBox17.Text
cellVal22 = Me.TextBox18.Text
cellVal23 = Me.TextBox19.Text
cellVal24 = Me.TextBox20.Text
cellVal25 = Me.TextBox21.Text
cellVal26 = Me.TextBox22.Text
cellVal27 = Me.TextBox23.Text
cellVal28 = Me.TextBox24.Text
cellVal29 = Me.TextBox25.Text
cellVal30 = Me.TextBox26.Text
cellVal31 = Me.TextBox27.Text
cellVal32 = Me.TextBox28.Text
cellVal33 = Me.TextBox29.Text
cellVal34 = Me.TextBox30.Text

RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal1
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AJ" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal2
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("A" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal3
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AH" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal4
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("B" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal5
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("C" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal6
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("D" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal7
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("E" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal8
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("F" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal9
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("G" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal10
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("H" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal11
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("I" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal12
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("J" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal13
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("K" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal14
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("L" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal15
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("M" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal16
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("N" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal17
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("O" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal18
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("P" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal19
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Q" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal20
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("R" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal21
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("S" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal22
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("T" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal23
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("U" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal24
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("V" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal25
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("W" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal26
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("X" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal27
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Y" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal28
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("Z" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal29
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AA" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal30
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AB" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal31
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AC" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal32
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AD" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal33
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AF" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal34

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub cmbListItem1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub optionCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Entry As Variant

    ' MonthName(Month(Now)) - Will return the name of the current Month
    For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SH.Name = MonthName(month(Now)) Then
            Set WrkSheet = SH
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem1
        For Each Entry In [List1]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
        .Value = MonthName(month(Now))
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem2
        For Each Entry In [List2]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With
    'fill the combo box
    With Me.cmbListItem3
        For Each Entry In [List3]
            .AddItem Entry
        Next Entry
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you would like to achieve with `Range("AI" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`? In particular, you are looking for the first empty cell of which column?

Comment: Imagine a woorkbook that has 14 sheets. First sheet is where the userform will open and have instructions on how to use the userform. sheet2 is where the lists are stored for the combobox, this sheet is hidden. Sheet 3-15 are the name of the month. Sheet 3 is January sheet 4 February. The columns of each sheet go froom A-AJ. You are the user. You fill the form out and select January for the month when you hit the submit button the data on the form goes into the sheet "January" Lets say you have another entry for January this entry should populate to the next line. This is what I am trying todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% aware of the design of your application, but I think the following will help:

```
Range("AI" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

is an invalid syntax. I think what you want is `Range("AI" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`. What this does, is looking at the first empty row, found below the last used row in column `AI`. But it needs to be modified a bit..

`Range` here refers probably to the `ActiveSheet`, which is not the month sheet, but the sheet where the Userform lives. In general, `Range` is a shortcut for either `Activeheet.Range` (if the code is in a `VBA` module) or it refers to the sheet in which it is entered, (if it is entered in a sheet module), and it can be dangerous occasionally.

A good practice is to fully qualify the range: `Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` instead: this guarantees that you are looking at the last row of the targeted sheet, column `AI`.

Then, why go to `lastrow + 1` instead of `lastrow`?

Keep also in mind that the range for `Integers` is limited till `32,767`, and there will be an error whenever the row number exceeds this value. I would use `Long` instead. Actually, `Integers` are internally converted to `Long`s anyway (but still throw an error if they exceed their range!), so why not use longs in the fist place.

I hope this gets you started, but let me know if any amendment would help by commenting below.

Best,
Ioannis

PS: also, you have done too much laborious work, maybe consider defining arrays instead of all these variables.

**EDIT:**

`it is skipping a row per each entry submited`

This is because it identifies `RwLast`, which is the first row with empty cells, and it writes the new content one row below:

```
Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & RwLast + 1).Value = cellVal1
```

and so on. To fix this, change

```
RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

to

```
RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

**EDIT2:**

Adding `Application.EnableEvents=False` guarantees that nothing will fire automatically while the `Sub btnSubmit_Click()` is executed. However, we need to be careful. Subroutine should start like this:

```
Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
```

and end like this

```
errHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Then there is nothing in `btnSubmit_Click` that changes `Row 2` of `shtCmb` **unless** `WrkSheet = Worksheets(shtCmb)`**and** `RwLast = 1`. It is not clear how `WrkSheet` is defined but I assume you have taken care of that.

Comment: Hey thanks so much!! I will try this back at work tomorrow and let you know the out come. ugh I am so hoping this works. :)

Comment: No worries!
It soulf work, but  even if it does not do so immediately it won't need more than a couple of iterations, and people here are pretty quick :)

Comment: Working for the most part. Only 2 issues now. First issue is it still changes the entry in row two whenever you add a new entry, however it also places the data into another row. Second issue is it is skipping a row per each entry submited.

Comment: For the second issue I added an edit. For the first issue: in which `sheet` it changes the entries in row `2`? Is it at the first sheet? Let me know. I think the code till the `RwLast` definition must be `OK` (i.e., innocent).

Comment: The season why the second row is overwritten is that the `_Change` events of your boxes are firing. This can happen if the `_initialize` event of the `userform` is triggered, because it populates (changes) the boxes. Are there any other events? the `_initialize` event of the userform should only fire when you first load it..

Comment: I re-posted the code with corrections. All of the _Intialize is at the bottom of the code. I am unsure.

Comment: I am just unsure what I should do about the initialize or which one is affecting the line spacing.

Comment: can you check if the **Edit** solves your second issue (line spacing)? The `btnSubmit_Click()` cannot change the entry of the second row.. If you refer to the second row entry in column `AI`, this changes every time you type something in `cmbListItem1`. To check it further, can you add `Application.EnabeEvents=False` at the very beginning of `btnSubmit_Click()` and `Application.EnabeEvents=True` at the very end? Then let us know if it still changes the second row?

Comment: Okay so I get ar error. Run-time error 438 Object doesnt support this property or method. I put the Application.EnabeEvents=False underneath the Private Sub btnSubmit_Click() then I put Application.EnabeEvents=True right above the End Sub on the submit button

Comment: Sorry! **`Application.EnableEvents`** (not `enabe` :) )

Comment: All Right we are almost there. It is still skipping a line How should I go about fixing it?

Comment: Remove the `.Offset(1, 0)` part from the `RwLast` definition: `RwLast = Worksheets(shtCmb).Range("AI" & Worksheets(shtCmb).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` :)

Comment: Alright. That fixed that and we are back to Row 2 changing the name and data each time i make a seperate entry. It is making seperate entries on each line but line 2 also makes or addes changes. :(

Comment: does this happen even when you set `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` and then `True`?

Comment: So how do I fix this??

Comment: If you use `Application.EnableEvents` then you can guarantee that this subroutine will not interfere with row 2. Row 2 entries will change only when you type something into any `cmbListItem`, as it is told to do so.

Comment: I did that. I will re-post my code so you can see where i did this.

Comment: Three things: (i) try to step through it: by hitting `F8` you can execute one line at a time. Then you can see exactly what happens and when row 2 changes. (ii) Please see my edit: using `EnableEvents` needs error handling (which has to be in the sub in the first place). (iii) Can you please post a link to the sheet (with minimal data)? I am curious to see what is going on..

Comment: I dont have a link to it but I can e-mail it to you.

Comment: When I click F8 it goes to Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() then the next F8 goes to For Each SH In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets and loops through it a few times before it goes to With Me.cmbListItem1 and loops through that several times.

Comment: See this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx. Place the cursor to this line: `shtCmb = Me.cmbListItem1.Value`. Hit `F9` Line will go red. Then try to execute the submit button, it will stop at that line. Hit `F8` from there onward. Then see when it writes stuff to row 2. Make sure you reach the line that turns `Application.EnableEvents = True` again!

Comment: Yes, I can have a look at it but only a bit later, need to work now :)
My email in on my prof.

Comment: Maybe I am blind today or just cant see it but here is my e-mail. garymcarrolljr@yahoo.com send me one and I will attach and send back.

Comment: In my Cobe were I put Private Sub TextBox21_Change()
WrkSheet.Range("V2").Value = Me.TextBox21.Text
End Sub should I take out the number 2 from "V2" and leave it just V? or should I change "Change" to something else?

Comment: @loannis I just posted the updated code and it works. Thanks again for all of your help!!